Developing an ipv4 addressing scheme for the vlans
What is the assign subnets table (Network Address, Subnet Mask, First/Last usable address, Broadcast address) of these vlans:
Vlan 99 (IT): 12 hosts /
Vlan 10 (S): 58 hosts /
Vlan 20 (L): 115 hosts
Knowing that the base network address is
192.168.10.0/24

This seems a lot like a homework question? Use  https://visualsubnetcalc.com/ or https://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html if that's what you need.

See this Q&A over at NE for all about subnetting.
